# What is 'cast error' about in Node.js? I can't figure out what's wrong

Tags: node.js

This is the error message

```
{ [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id"]
  message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'undefined',
  path: '_id',
  reason: undefined }
```

I'm trying to make web app using Node.js, and I have no idea what's this about.

This is router code

```
app.post("/fighter/:id/fight", function(req, res) {

    Fight.create(req.body.fight, function(err, createdFight) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        else 
            res.redirect("/fighter/" + req.body.id);
        Fighter.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundFighter){

            if (err)
                console.log(err)
            else {
                foundFighter.fights.push(createdFight);
                foundFighter.save();

            } 

        })
    })


})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using MongoDB and the error message means that it can't create an ObjectID from your request `body`.

```
app.post("/fighter/:id/fight", function(req, res) {
   if ( ! req.body.fight ) { return res.json( { error: "fight is empty" } ) };

   Fight.create(req.body.fight, function(err, createdFight) { ... } );
} );
```